Artifactory Remote Repository does not automatically download uncached Artifacts
I'm using a remote repository in artifactory to download Jenkins Plugins from https://get.jenkins.io/plugins. But I'm running into one problem. When a plugin is not cached, I always get a 404 and cannot download the plugin.
When inspecting the remote repo through the repository explorer, I can see lots of jenkins plugins with lots of versions. However none of then are cached. This seems valid because I never tried to download them before. So when I copy the "URL to file" for a given plugin (say http://<MY_URL>/artifactory/jenkins-remote-plugin-2/chucknorris/1.4/chucknorris.hpi) I always get a 404.
When I right-click on the chucknorris/1.4/chucknorris.hpi file and choose "Download" then the hpi file is downloaded (to my local computer). And then I can use the "URL to file" as well.
But I would like to not manually download the artifact first. Is there a way to tell a remote repo that it should always download artifacts, that are not cached?
Since I aim to use this in an ansible playbook, I would really like to avoid manually downloading artifacts first.
Thanks and best regards. Sebastian

I believe that you need to use this URL http://mirrors.jenkins.io/plugins in the remote repo which is mentioned in this KB
I have tested it with version 7.71 and it worked
